# TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis

Tags: java, time

I did not understand the explanation at oracle, what is this piece of code actually doing?

```
final int maximumDelay = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1000);
```

Comment: Why would one need a method for this? I am confused.

Comment: German University... ^^

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It converts 1000 seconds into milliseconds, then truncates the result from `long` to `int`.